# Como pegar 40px X 40px de toda imagem?

Tags: css

Como faço para uma determinada resolução de toda imagem? Por exemplo, tenho essa imagem: [image]

Mas no CSS irei pegar somente 20px dela. Não dá para usar `height` e `width`.

Comment: Quer um pedaço dela (20px largura e 20px altura) ou que redimensionar?

Comment: Preciso de um pedaço

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando a imagem como `background-image`, por exemplo:
Esta é a imagem em que vamos estar a trabalhar neste exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o código para mostrar apenas `40px` da imagem acima será:

```css
.minhaImagem {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKGy3.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-position: -348px -326px; /* Escolha a parte da image que queres mostrar aumentando/diminuindo estes valores */
}
```

```html
<div class="minhaImagem"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a propriedade `CSS` **`clip`**:

```
clip: rect(topo, direita, rodape, esquerda);
```

**Antes**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Depois**

```
<style type="text/css">
    #minhaImagem
    {
        position: absolute;;
        clip: rect(0px,20px,20px,0px);
    }
</style>

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/anKc1.gif" width="40" height="40" id="minhaImagem" />
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]